# Upgrade from 12.04 to 13.10

Tags: drivers

Do I need to download drivers before I upgrade to 13.10? I have Asus x201e, but cannot find the drivers on the Asus website.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't have to download drivers.  If your computer is working with 12.04 it will certainly work with a newer version.

Linux Kernel tends to aggregate drivers and provide native support for new hardware on every new version.  So you don't have to worry about.